# Apeche service of Xampp not install in win7 64 bit

Tags: xampp

While i am trying to install the Apache service then It shows Service not install. How can i solve this problem?

xampp version:3.2.2[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7lKM.png)

Answer (score 0):

That means that apache cannot be currently installed as a service. It happens because the system failed to start apache.
Try to run it pressing the start button, to see if you can get more details about the error.

One of the most common thing is that the port 80 (or the port you have configured to serve web) is being used by another application such as Skype.

In order to solve this, you have to close that application and stop all services using that port and configure the application or service to run in another port.

To see what process is using your port: [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows)

Comment: Skype is not using that port. I have unchecked that seting of skype. I also clicked to start button of xampp and shows a message "[Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app..." and nothing happen.                 
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    58.97.172.119:1563     216.163.188.45:80      CLOSE_WAIT

Comment: While i go to the Apache folder and try to install using "apache_installservice.bat" then the CMD window shows : The service name is invalid.

Comment: can you post your /xampp/apache/logs/error.log ?
Also check if  in Event viewer (Control panel -> View Event Logs). Under the Even viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application there is something useful to determinate which is problem.
99% of the time is the port being used by another process or blocked by firewall or antivirus

Comment: Firewall and antivirous are turned off. I think those will make problem while running a service. But in my case i am unagle to install the service. anyway, there is no error.log in  /xampp/apache/logs/ directory. ther is only a text file name instal. it contain: Installing Apache HTTP Server 2.x with
 DomainName    = example.com
 ServerName    = www.example.com
 ServerAdmin   = admin@example.com
 ServerPort    = 80
 ServerSslPort = 443
 ServerRoot    = c:/Apache24
Rewrote docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in
 to c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

Comment: my sql service is install and run properly. but while i try to install the apeche service then get message:Installing Apache2.4 as an Service
Now we Start Apache2.4 :)
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: if you run it pressing the start button on the right (instead of the service button of the left column), does it work?
If so, then what you have to so is include the path.

Go to : My Computer(right click)->Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables->User variables 
and locate “PATH” 
There include at the end of the string, the path to your apache installation.

Alternatively, you can directly run 
YOUR PATH\xampp\apache\apache_installservice.bat directly , right click and run it as an administrator

Comment: Yes i do that but it replay error which i have mentioned before. Thanks a lot for your help. i also try to run this latest version in my another laptop also but failed. sql service run but apache not. At las i have download another old portable virsion: "xampp-portable-win32-5.6.20-0-VC11" and now this version is working. I think the latest version: "xampp-win32-7.0.5-0-VC14" is not for me. Thank you again.